# Compiling Unicode with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, visual-studio-2019, unicode-string

I try to compile [this C++17 code](https://github.com/abergmeier/CnC_Remastered_Multiplatform/blob/ab5a4aef1dadab758e7e18e3cfb16dc3c9fed40f/TIBERIANDAWN/WIN32LIB/UNICODE_TEST.CPP) on VS2019:

```
int main() {

  if(!testCodepointEncode(U'\u221A', '\xFB') ||
     !testCodepointEncode(U'\u0040', '\x40') ||
     !testCodepointEncode(U'\u03A3', '\xE4') ||
     !testCodepointEncode(U'', '\xFE')) {
    return 1;
  }
  // Test 1 byte
  if(!testEncode("\u0040", "\x40")) {
    return 2;
  }

  // Test 2 byte
  if(!testEncode("\u03A3", "\xE4")) {
    return 3;
  }

  // Test 3 byte
  if(!testEncode("\u2502", "\xB3")) {
    return 4;
  }

  // Test 4 byte
  if(!testEncode("", "\xFE")) {
    return 5;
  }

  if(!testArray("F ⌠ Z", "\x46\x20\xF4\x20\x5A")) {
    return 6;
  }

  if(!testView("F ⌠ Z", "\x46\x20\xF4\x20\x5A")) {
    return 7;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works fine with gcc and clang on Linux, but MSVC complains:

```
UNICODE_TEST.CPP(65,27): error C2015: too many characters in constant 
UNICODE_TEST.CPP(75,18): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u03A3' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) 
UNICODE_TEST.CPP(80,18): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u2502' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
```

I tried setting the current codepage to UTF-8, but the errors persisted.

How is one supposed to compile this code on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at what you are doing on this line:

```
if(!testEncode("\u03A3", "\xE4")) {
```

References the string literal:

```
"\u03a3"
```

You are trying to express a UTF-16 character inside an 8-bit (char*) string literal.  That just won't work.  That's kind of equivalent to doing this:

```
char sz[2] = {0};
sz[0] = (char)(0x03a3);
```

And expecting `sz[0]` to hold the original UTF-16 character.  That's what the compiler is warning you about.

If you want to express a 16-bit unicode character inside a string literal, use a wide string.  Like follows with the `L` prefix:

```
L"\u03a3"
```

The above is a string literal which holds a signal wide-char character: `L"Σ"`

And if we really want to be pendantic, we could say this to portably express a UTF-16 character string, use the `u` prefix:

```
u"\u03a3"
```

But on Windows wchar_t is 16-bit, so it doesn't really matter.

You'll probably need to fix your `testEncode` functions to expect a `const wchar_t*` instead of a `const char*` parameter.  (I'm honestly not sure what your `test*` functions are doing, but some of your parameters look suspcious if the goal is to confirm UTF8 to UTF16 conversions)

If you want to express a UTF-8 string in code, you could say this:

```
"\xCE\xA3"
```

The above is the UTF-8 representation for a sigma `Σ` character as UTF-8 string

Comment: Why does it work on gcc and clang then? There, `"\u03a3"` gives me a `const char[3]` which AFAIK is then UTF-8 representation of the 03A3 codepoint (2 bytes) + `\0`.

Comment: A casual look into the C spec says nothing about `\u` beyond codepoints. So are you implying that the MSVC implementation only interprets `\u` "correctly" in the context of types > `sizeof(char)`?

Comment: By definition, if I interpret the C++ spec correctly, `"\u03a3"` is considered "ill-formed".  Hence, the compiler vendors are free to implement the conversion anyway they see fit.  My answer still stands - even for clang and gcc.

Comment: Can you post a link to the paragraph of the C++ spec. Would be interesting whether it differs from C.

Comment: I'm not finding an exact passage [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) that matches up to my interpretation, but do read the section starting on page 15 wrt to character literals and string literals.   I am not a language lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. My solution was to replace `` with `\U00020C96`, which works then on gcc, clang and msvc. The warnings still persist on msvc but the binary encoding seems to be unaffected.

Comment: @selbie "*If you want to express a UTF-8 string in code, you could say this: `"\xCE\xA3"`*" - or, you can use `u8"\u03a3"` instead, or even `u8"Σ"`

Comment: `u8"\u03a3"` is fine, but I discourage `u8"Σ"`  heavily - because it assumes you consistently save the source file as UTF8.  It's very easy in a team environment for a source control system or someone with a different editor setting to "save as" something other than UTF8 and create an issue later on.